# Playing Diablo 3 Hardcore with Windows 10 Automatic Update

Tags: diablo-iii, windows-10

I almost exclusively play hardcore mode, and I much prefer it. The only downside, as I see it, is that lagging out or disconnecting may kill you (I'm fine with *any* other kind of death).

Now, I recently updated to Windows 10, and with that comes the fact that [you cannot disable automatic updates](http://www.howtogeek.com/219166/you-won%E2%80%99t-be-able-to-disable-or-delay-windows-updates-on-windows-10-home/). Now, I could totally see a situation where a download suddenly starts and causes me to lag in-game. This could apply to other online games as well.

Is there anything built into Windows 10 that prevents this from happening with online games? I could imagine they would want to disrupt the user experience as little as possible. If no, is this something I should realistically worry about, and what (if anything) can be done about it?

(*I'm not interested in answers suggesting switching from Windows 10*)

**Edit:** As said in comments, online games have different needs from other types of media, such as being more dependent on latency than bandwidth. This question was specifically intended to ask how *gaming* is affected by the changes presented in Windows 10, and for this particular question I'm only interested in facts about the operating system *as a gaming platform*, and how it *directly affects my gaming experience*.

Comment: You could try rescheduling the updates... Or disable `wuaserv` (system service). | Also, I generally don't get any extra lag while an update is being downloaded.

Comment: [btw, you **cannot** disable updates even on Windows 10 Pro via the control panel. You can defer upgrades, which are different to the everyday update.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWekM.png)

Comment: This is a question about Windows 10, not really about gaming.

Comment: Migrate to [su] maybe? Even if it is migrated there, [this question would be a duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/837946/disabling-windows-updates-for-windows-10)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how Windows 10 works, which isn't a gaming specific problem.

Comment: I think the more important question is - will Windows 10 force restart your PC while you're fighting that super difficult elite pack, because it decided that your update is more important?

Comment: If your router permits Quality of Service settings, make diablo 3 the highest priority so even if windows starts downloading a patch, you router will throttle the speed of the patch's download so your d3 experience is less affected, if it even affects it at all.

Comment: I think it's a gaming question, as it is specifically about how gameplay quality is affected by the platform the game is played on. However, I agree that it's close to the border between Super User and Arqade, as it could easily be extended to "a generic application" instead of a game. That said, games may require different standards of connectivity compared to other applications (you can't _buffer_ a game, for instance).

Comment: @Chippies - You can always delay the restart, up to 48 hours though.

Comment: I think this could perhaps be adapted to all games,but very helpful for this site. I have a similar issue, where battlefield shuts down due to an automatic update. At the end of the day, windows 10 has a feature that impedes on gaming. Asking about any way to disable it, especially for the purpose of being able to play the game, should be on topic. Asking "is windows 10 bad" does sound like speculation, though.

Comment: @aytimothy - But what about my 48 hour gaming binges?!?!?!

Comment: @Robotnik Disable `wuauserv`. (In Plain English: `Disable Windows Update`)

Comment: @aytimothy heh yeah I know, sorry tongue in cheek doesn't carry across text too well :-P

Comment: @Robotnik Glad you cleared it up. *sigh*. I guess that's the downsides of text-only communication: No tone or visual gestures.

Comment: You really need to clarify your question, and narrow it to be gaming specific, then.  As it stands, not a single answer even *mentions* a game, which is why I voted to close it in the first place.  Let's at least *try* to make this specific to gaming, shall we?

Comment: @Frank I made some minor edits and added some mention of the difference between games and other online media. In my mind this is a gaming question, but I'm subject to author's subjectivity. Do you have any concrete suggestions? The view count and upvotes suggest to me that people are interested and it's worth improving the question as much as possible.

Comment: @Svj0hn This is a useful and helpful question and obviously related to gaming.  There's no reason to worry just because one person doesn't like it.

Comment: I run W10 myself and have been since the early tech preview. I've got around 30mb internet provided by sky in the UK. I also run HC Diablo 3 and can say I haven't had a single issue with Windows Update lagging my game out in several months of having this set up.

It's worth noting I have since reloaded with the full RC version of Windows 10 and I still have no issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly, Windows Update shouldn't lag your game, unless your internet connection is slow. I have a 256kB/s connection, and it doesn't seem to have any effect while playing games online.
*If at all, Windows Update tries not to affect the speed of your any other connections to the internet while it's updating.*

If you're really worried about Windows Update lagging up your system by downloading updates in the background, you can disable it by disabling the `wuaserv` service.

**Note:** You cannot disable it through the Control Panel or Settings App. The only way to do it is to go "under the hood".
This answer applies both to Windows 7, 8, 10 Home/Professional/Ultimate/whatever-fancy-name-they-use/Home Premium/Basic/Enterprise

---

1. Open the services manager.
   *Try pressing Win + R then typing **services.msc***
2. Look for **Windows Update** (or its actual name, **wuauserv**) and right click on it.
3. Select "Properties"
4. Change "Startup Type" to **Disabled** in the Property dialog box.
5. Select the "Stop" button if it is running and select "OK" to confirm your changes.

Comment: Useful, +1... Do you have a source for the "_Windows Update tries not to affect the speed of your any other connections to the internet while it's updating._" claim? I would be interested to read more about that functionality.

Comment: @Svj0hn Nope I don't have proof. It's based on what I noticed on my net traffic and since the programs I use don't log stuff, I can't post that proof.

Comment: I can tell you that Windows Update seems to use a fixed rate, but this rate is not scaled to your connection! So if you have something in the range of 5 to 20Mb/s, there might be some issues with updates. I have measured in two computers, one connected to a 1Mb/s connection and another to a 50Mb/s connection, and both of them updated at around 100kb/s. Note that 100kbps is almost 80% of 1Mb/s (remember that ISPs measure speed in mega*bits*), so depending oun your connection, it might be quite fatal for gaming.

Comment: When Windows 10 decides to download some new Bluetooth drivers, it manages to use all of my 10mbit/s connection to the point that other devices on the network can't even browse websites. Since Windows 10 uses peer-to-peer update distribution by default, it is capable of dramatically impacting one's internet connection.

Comment: @aytimothy It seems your experience is based on a relatively overpowered network connection, not on Windows 10 having a decent network handling.

Comment: 256 MB/s is *way* more than your average person will have...
@Kroltan 100 kb is about 10% of 1 Mb. If you are referring to kilo*bytes*, please use k**B**.

Comment: @JacobRaihle Yes, I used lowercase Bs. I usually use KiB to denote binary scale. Either way, the point was relating to the approximate percentage of available bandwidth, not exact values.

Comment: @Kroltan This is a matter of bytes vs. bits, not base 2 vs. base 10. And there's a big difference between 10% and 80%.

Comment: Usually the download speed depends on when it starts the downloads. If you have an active connection (ie. watching YouTube on 4K) which takes nearly all your bandwidth, it automatically throttles. Otherwise - Full steam ahead (it uses the full bandwidth)

Comment: Guys, my bad: It's 256kB, not 256MB

Comment: Accepting this answer as it contains a simple way of disabling the updates, and hints to the other part of the question (should I worry...).

Answer (score 6):

Windows Update uses BITS (Background Internet Transfer Service). This service is designed with several goals in mind, one of which is minimizing impact to other network applications.

> Background transfers are optimal in that BITS uses idle network bandwidth to transfer the files and will increase or decrease the rate at which files are transferred based on the amount of idle network bandwidth available. If a network application begins to consume more bandwidth, BITS decreases its transfer rate to preserve the user's interactive experience.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362708(v=vs.85).aspx

The landing page for [BITS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968799(v=vs.85).aspx) provides the link to its usage in Windows Update:

> **Note**: BITS is most commonly used by Windows to download updates to your local system.

All that said, Windows 10 should not impact your network gaming experience.

Comment: Does BITS back off to avoid impacting latency, though?  Most games don't use a lot of bandwidth, and are just sensitive to latency.  If windows can de-prioritize BITS relative to everything else, that might help some, too.

Comment: Don't know if it can de-prioritize like you say, but I think with group policies you can restrict BITS to a certain schedule so that it does nothing during certain times of the day and/or week.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a bit more technically savvy then you can block inbound/outbound connections to the actual update websites:

http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com

http://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com

https://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com

http://*.update.microsoft.com

https://*.update.microsoft.com

http://*.windowsupdate.com

http://download.windowsupdate.com

http://download.microsoft.com

http://*.download.windowsupdate.com

http://wustat.windows.com

http://ntservicepack.microsoft.com

http://stats.microsoft.com

https://stats.microsoft.com

[**^ Source**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b596aa81-2775-496c-b159-dcfc5c5bf22d/windows-update-ip-addresses-range-and-subnet-mask-for-windows-server-2008?forum=winserversecurity)

You should be able to configure this within your OS but if not then the router-level would work just as well or maybe better.

Comment: Routing all these domains to 127.0.0.1 in the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) used to do the trick, is that still possible in Windows 10?

Comment: @Mast I do not have Windows 10 but if you wanted to try it out then it should still be viable. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: I know how to do it and I don't have Windows 10 either. I'm waiting with my upgrade till I know how to prevent trouble like this from happening ^^

Comment: @Mast I tried that. It killed all my Metro/Modern UI app traffic. (No metro app could connect to the internet without Fiddler, even with the `hosts` file cleared). | That didn't fix itself until I did a full reinstall. Refreshing the system doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @aytimothy Yes, Windows Metro apps use those same domains so you lose a lot of traffic at once. It's a hardcore solution for a hardcore problem :-)

Comment: @Mast No, I meant Edge cannot connect to the internet, whereas Chrome and any other desktop browser can. (Only when the developer mode is enabled, with Fiddler it can connect. And even still, some connections are blocked due to the Fiddler's limitations and the way it's handled; not with a domain name, but pure IP).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If BITS is designed not to cut into existing bandwidth, it sucks at it: I've upgraded two machines to Windows 10, and in each case Windows Update would crush the network connection (about 3 Mbps).

In the end I decided to [throttle BITS using the Group Policy editor](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sus/archive/2008/06/30/wsus-how-to-throttle-bits.aspx), which you can access by typing 'Edit group policy' from the Start menu. Set it to something reasonable during your typical work/gaming hours; no more problems and you still get updates.

Answer (score -1):

This answer covers QoS (Quality of Service) settings that most routers have. Some don't, so check if your router support QoS.

3 articles covering QoS :

1. [PcWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2689995/quality-of-service-explained-how-routers-with-strong-qos-make-better-home-networks.html)
2. [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/326543/ensure-a-fast-internet-connection-when-you-need-it?utm_expid=66866090-48.Ej9760cOTJCPS_Bq4mjoww.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca)
3. [How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/75660/the-beginners-guide-to-qos-on-your-router/)

These settings will vary from routers to routers, so read your router manual to use QoS in a way that will provide you with the best gaming experience.

I recommend only setting the games you want as highest priority and let the router manage the rest. From there, your router will make sure the packets the games you set as highest priority will be treated before any other packets. This should let your games' latency be low even if Windows decide to update.

You could set windows update as a lower priority so that you further control the download speed of the updates but that would slow it down whenever something else use bandwidth, not just when you're gaming.